# sql id count for each product

Tags: sql, count

I have this tabel, where i would like to count the product for each Customer ID.
I have 3 different product_id's

My current tabel looks like this:

| Customer_id | Product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 |
| 1 | 1002 |
| 1 | 1003 |
| 2 | 1001 |
| 2 | 1003 |
| 3 | 1001 |
| 3 | 1002 |
| 4 | 1003 |

I would like to create this tabel:

| Customer_id | Product_id_1001 | Product_id_1002 | Product_id_1003 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Is it possible?

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using

Comment: If someone later inserts product 1004, do you expect your query to suddenly return a new product_id_1004 column?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the conditional aggregation :

```
select Customer_id,
       count(case when Product_id = 1001 then 1 end) as Product_id_1001,
       count(case when Product_id = 1002 then 1 end) as Product_id_1002,
       count(case when Product_id = 1003 then 1 end) as Product_id_1003
from mytable
group by Customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use PIVOT clause:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl (CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID) AS
        ( Select 1, 1001 From Dual Union All
          Select 1, 1002 From Dual Union All
          Select 1, 1003 From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 1001 From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 1003 From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 1001 From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 1002 From Dual Union All
          Select 4, 1003 From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select      * 
From        tbl
    PIVOT ( Count(PRODUCT_ID) For PRODUCT_ID IN(1001 "PRODUCT_ID_1001", 1002 "PRODUCT_ID_1002", 1003 "PRODUCT_ID_1003" ) )
Order By    CUSTOMER_ID
```

```sql
/*    --  R e s u l t :
CUSTOMER_ID PRODUCT_ID_1001 PRODUCT_ID_1002 PRODUCT_ID_1003
----------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
          1               1               1               1
          2               1               0               1
          3               1               1               0
          4               0               0               1   */
```